# makefile pattern with multiple variants

Tags: makefile

I tried to make a makefile with patterns.

I want to have two variants:
when i write `make` it should just compile the list of files.
when i write `make run` it should run the respective files.

this is my current makefile:

```
files = test test1 test2

all: $(files)
$(files): % : %.scala
    scalac $<

run: $(files)
$(files): % : %.scala
    scala $<
```

now, regardless of whether i do `make` or `make run` it always executes the `scala` command and never `scalac`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a duplicate target:

`$(files): % : %.scala`

remove one of the targets (probably the second line was added by you)